# Creating/drawing "freehand" polygon features in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, digitizing

I installed the Freehand Editing plugin but it doesn't seem to work with the latest version of QGIS; the icon appears on the Ditizing Toolbar but the icon is disabled.

Is there any way to use a freehand drawing/editing using a Wacom tablet and a pen in QGIS 2.2?

Comment: What OS are you running? How did you install QGIS 2.2?  I just tried on my Windows7 system, with QGIS2.2 installed via OSGEO4W and it worked fine. Are you sure you have a polygon or line layer, and that it's editable?

Comment: Update: I just tried using the "Freehand Editing" plugin on QGIS 2.14 and it is greyed out (disabled) even when editing of a polygon layer is enabled.

Comment: I just tested the Freehand Editing plugin on QGIS 2.18 on Windows 10, and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you might have missed pressing the `Toggle Editing` button to enable you to save new entities created with the digitizing toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

There was a note [here](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Freehand-editing-tp5042615p5045292.html) that you have to restart QGIS for it to run. That's not standard for most of the plugins I've tried, but it worked for me.

I still can't find any instructions or other use info for the tool, however...